# Odoo. How do I force Odoo to create related records on import?

Tags: csv, import, odoo

Ok, let's say I'm importing products and they have a brand field (this is from a custom module and it is a many2one relation). A brand has only a name. If I designate a new external id and name for the new brand it won't let me import, because it says it could not find that external id in the db. But how could I just force it to CREATE a brand with that external id? Or am I forced to import brands first and then products?

Comment: You can try by having just names of the brand. While importing products just give the column name for brands as the field name specified in the customer module py file. The while importing just put the names of the brands in that coulumn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using import you are expected to provide external id (xmlid of the record) or database id (real id from db) - first you have to create records to add a reference to them.

Comment: Yes, I know, I'm looking for a way to create and reference records on import. Let's say I'm importing a product and I specify a brand that's not yet in the database, but I provide the required fields, how can I force Odoo to just create a brand with those fields? Or is it impossible?

Comment: It is impossible, you have to create them first, otherwise you will get an error that external id was not found in database.